# Serilog LoggerConfiguration write to different Sink by context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, logging, serilog

I have web asp.net MVC application using `IdentityServer3`.
I want to split logging to different Sink.
I want to write `IdentityServer3` logging to `Trace`, `EventLog("IdentityServer3")` and `SerilogWeb.Classic.Enrichers` to database `MSSqlServer`.

My configuration is:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Trace()
                .WriteTo.EventLog("IdentityServer3")
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                //all after this i want to write in database
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer("connectionString", "Log")
                .Enrich.With(new HttpRequestIdEnricher())
                .Enrich.With(new HttpRequestRawUrlEnricher())
                .Enrich.With(new HttpRequestUserAgentEnricher())
                .Enrich.With(new UserNameEnricher())
                .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write a subset of events to a sink, use `WriteTo.Logger()` and the `Filter` directive. Each case will be similar; here's the Identity Server one:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("IdentityServer3"))
        .WriteTo.Trace()
        .WriteTo.EventLog("IdentityServer3"))
    // <snip>
```

You can apply enrichers either at the outermost level, so that they enrich all events, or on one of the nested logger configurations.